# Provide IntelliSense / Validation for custom Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to provide IntelliSense information and validation for the parameters passed to a custom Tag Helper?

Sample

```html
<div the-controller="Home" the-action="WrongActionName"></div>
```

I want to mark `the-action` as invalid as it does not exist in the Controller `HomeController` for example.

In addition I want to get the same IntelliSense experience for `the-controller` and `the-action` as build in Tag Helpers, e.g.

```html
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
<!--the form content -->
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if `Home/WrongActionName` exists with `the-controller` and `the-action` If so,I think js can help you.

Comment: Yes, I want to check this at design time

Comment: If you want to check it with vs by default,I'm afraid not.